# Can you use Sign In with Google for Web and require that the user have used a passkey for that account?

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible to use Sign In with Google for Web and require that the user have used a passkey for their account?  (Yes, I know that in a perfect world we probably shouldn't care.  In this case there is a very specific - and unusual - nonnegotiable hard requirement that says the user MUST at some point in time have used a passkey.  We actually don't care about this specific login instance though; any passkey use at any time for anything whatsoever marks the user as good enough.)